# Issue while converting string to number

Tags: typescript

The issue identified is specific to this number. Also tried ParseInt and ParseFloat and result are same.

> convertedNumber:number=0;
>
> this.convertedNumber=Number('178414025760337**17**');
>
> Output:178414025760337**16**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having issues because your number is **bigger than the maximum** that can be encoded by a `Number`, which is `2^53` (`Number.MAX_VALUE = 9007199254740991`).

You will have to use a library such as `BigInt` to handle your number.

See the [bigint typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#bigint).

```js
const big1 = BigInt('17841402576033717');
const big2 = BigInt('17841402576033717');
const big3 = big1 + big2;

console.log(big3.toString());
```